# How to change background color of ul li elements in autosuggest react component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Iam using react Autosuggest component for city country list. When an input is given the suggested list of cities name with their respective countries is displayed. I am able to change the background color while hovering, but, I want to change when key pressed 'up' or 'down'. Following is the code for reference

Form.js

```
const getSuggestions = value => {
  const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase(); 
  const inputLength = inputValue.length;

  return inputLength === 0 ? [] : cities.filter(data =>
    data.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
  ).slice(0,4);
};
 
// When suggestion is clicked, Autosuggest needs to populate the input
// based on the clicked suggestion.
const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.name
 
const renderSuggestion = suggestion => 
(
  
  <table className='auto-complete'>
        <tbody>
          <ArrowTooltip title={suggestion.name + ', ' + countries.getName(suggestion.country,"en")} placement="top">
          <tr>
          <td style={{ width: '88%' }} dangerouslySetInnerHTML=
          {highlight(suggestion.name, suggestion.value)}></td>
          <td style={{ width: '12%' }}>{suggestion.country}</td>
        </tr>
          </ArrowTooltip>
        </tbody>
      </table>
);

class Form extends React {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: [] 
    };
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
    if(method == 'up' || method == 'down') {
      // Here the value is triggered when key pressed
      console.log('KEY UP/DOWN')
    }
    
  };
 
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };
 
  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to clear suggestions.
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };

  onSuggestionSelected = (event, {suggestion}) => {
    const isSuggestion = true
    this.props.getWeather(suggestion, isSuggestion)
  }


render() {
    const { value, suggestions} = this.state;
 
    // Autosuggest will pass through all these props to the input.
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'Search City...',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

<Autosuggest
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
        onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
/>
}

}

export default Form
```

CSS required for suggestions (which is to be styled)
Form.css

```
.react-autosuggest__suggestions-container {
    display: none;
  }

  .react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open {
    display: block;
    perspective: 1000px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px; 
    width: 180px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open, .react-autosuggest__input { 
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    }
  }

  .react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open li{
    transform-origin: top center;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background: #c7ecee;
  }

  /* Here the background color is changed on hovering each li */
  .react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open li:hover {
    background: #95afc0;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  }
```

As seen above, when the mouse is hovered over each elements background color changes, but, I want to change when key (up or down) is pressed. Any suggestions or changes??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add theme prop. Something like this:

```
<Autosuggest
      suggestions={suggestions}
      onSuggestionsFetchRequested={
      this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested
    }
    onSuggestionsClearRequested={
      this.onSuggestionsClearRequested
    }
    getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
    renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
    inputProps={inputProps}
    focusInputOnSuggestionClick={true}
    theme={{
      container: {
        display: "block",
        width: "100%",
        position: "absolute",
        borderTop: "none",
        borderBottom: "1px solid #aaa",
        borderLeft: "1px solid #aaa",
        borderRight: "1px solid #aaa",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        fontFamily: "Helvetica, sans-serif",
        fontWeight: 300,
        fontSize: "16px",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: "4px",
        borderBottomRightRadius: "4px",
        zIndex: 2,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0,
      },
      input: {
        marginBottom: 0,
        display: "block",
        width: "100%",
        height: "34px",
        padding: "6px 12px",
        fontSize: "14px",
        lineHeight: "1.4285",
        color: "#555",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        backgroundImage: "none",
        borderRadius: "4px",
        border: "1px solid #ccc",
      },
      suggestionHighlighted: {
        backgroundColor: "lightgrey", //magic line
        cursor:'pointer'
      },
    }}
  />
```